# Computer Algebra System for Homotopy Types of Finite Simplicial Sets

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

I hope this is the right place to ask the following question, if not please guide me towards the correct forum...

I want to show that two certain finite simplicial sets are not weakly homotopy equivalent. They are too large to prove it by hand, so I would like to write a computer program to check this for me. Problem is: I never worked with any CAS (I have a background in computer science though).

Before I write a math-engine from scratch, which existent language do you suggest to use? I will need the following features:

- Permutation groups
- Powers of a finite set $X^{\times n} = X \times ... \times X$
- $d$-skeleton of a degreewise finite simplicial set
- Unions of images of morphisms of simplicial sets
- rational/integral homology of a simplicial set, fundamental group, rational/integral homotopy type in decreasing order of likeliness.

I just tried to do my first steps in SAGE, but already ran into syntax problems. So I really want to make sure I choose the correct language for my task, before spending much time in the rabbit hole of familiarizing myself with a new language.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is uncomputable in full generality (essentially because it is uncomputable whether two finitely presented groups are isomorphic, which can be the fundamental groups of your simplicial sets).

Comment: That is correct. I don't really expect to be able to compute *everything* about my finite simplicial sets. For example the homotopy groups of spheres are complicated. My point is that I want to learn a language, which can do as much as possible. Maybe the fundamental groups are trivial? Maybe they are finite? The point is: I don't know.